# Como validar cpf com máscara em javascript?

Tags: javascript, validação

Galera Sou iniciante na área e queria saber como faço para validar cpf com máscara em javascript, eu andei pesquisando e não consegui achar um que fizesse os dois ao mesmo tempo.
Tenho um exemplo que tinha feito que no caso a validação era feita online, mas o site que eu usava a validação saiu do ar.
Desde Já Agradeço.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Validar CPF com Máscara by TchekiGamer</title>

  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <meta name="language" content="PT-BR"/>

    <script src="http://www.geradorcpf.com/scripts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.geradorcpf.com/jquery-1.2.6.pack.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.geradorcpf.com/jquery.maskedinput-1.1.4.pack.js"></script>

    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){  
      $(".cpf").mask("999.999.999-99");   

      $("#cpf").blur(function (){
        if($("#cpf").val() == '') {           
          $("#saida").html("Informe um CPF");         
          return false;   
        }    
        if(validarCPF($("#cpf").val())) {         
          $(".cpf").css('border-color','limegreen');     
        } 
        else {            
          $(".cpf").css('border-color','red');     
        } 
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">

    <div align="center" id="saida1">
      <label>Digite o seu cpf</label>
      <input name="cpf" type="text" class="cpf" id="cpf">
    </div>

    <div align="center" id="saida1">
      <label>Teste</label>
      <input name="teste" type="text" class="teste">
    </div>

    <div align="center" id="saida" class="style7"> <!--aparece mensagem de CPF Invalido--> </div>

  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usando a resposta do nosso amigo [Leo Caracciolo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/60252/leo-caracciolo) apenas acrescentei uma máscara para deixar bonitinho do conforme o seu pedido (máscara + validador).

```js
function ValidaCPF(){ 
 var RegraValida=document.getElementById("RegraValida").value; 
 var cpfValido = /^(([0-9]{3}.[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2})|([0-9]{11}))$/;  
 if (cpfValido.test(RegraValida) == true) { 
 console.log("CPF Válido"); 
 } else {  
 console.log("CPF Inválido"); 
 }
    }
  function fMasc(objeto,mascara) {
obj=objeto
masc=mascara
setTimeout("fMascEx()",1)
}

  function fMascEx() {
obj.value=masc(obj.value)
}

   function mCPF(cpf){
cpf=cpf.replace(/\D/g,"")
cpf=cpf.replace(/(\d{3})(\d)/,"$1.$2")
cpf=cpf.replace(/(\d{3})(\d)/,"$1.$2")
cpf=cpf.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{1,2})$/,"$1-$2")
return cpf
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="RegraValida" value="" name="RegraValida" onkeydown="javascript: fMasc( this, mCPF );"><input type="submit" value="Validar" onclick="ValidaCPF();">
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado Colega ,me ajudou muito, era exatamente o que eu estava precisando

Answer (score 2):

**Provável erro no seu arquivo.**

- O seu código funcionará se incluir a biblioteca que falta, exemplo:

  - `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`
- Seu arquivo tem um `</script>` a mais após a chamada do arquivo `jquery.maskedinput-1.1.4.pack.js` (não acarreta erro porém ...)

  > Para não ficar dependendo de outros sites, salve os arquivos .js no seu servidor
  >
  > **ou use o script abaixo**

**Com Javascript**

> Aproveitando a resposta do nosso amigo `brnTwp` **e acrescentando a validação de cpfs segundo a regra da receita federal** temos:

```js
function is_cpf (c) {

  if((c = c.replace(/[^\d]/g,"")).length != 11)
    return false

  if (c == "00000000000")
    return false;

  var r;
  var s = 0;

  for (i=1; i<=9; i++)
    s = s + parseInt(c[i-1]) * (11 - i);

  r = (s * 10) % 11;

  if ((r == 10) || (r == 11))
    r = 0;

  if (r != parseInt(c[9]))
    return false;

  s = 0;

  for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    s = s + parseInt(c[i-1]) * (12 - i);

  r = (s * 10) % 11;

  if ((r == 10) || (r == 11))
    r = 0;

  if (r != parseInt(c[10]))
    return false;

  return true;
}


function fMasc(objeto,mascara) {
obj=objeto
masc=mascara
setTimeout("fMascEx()",1)
}

  function fMascEx() {
obj.value=masc(obj.value)
}

function mCPF(cpf){
cpf=cpf.replace(/\D/g,"")
cpf=cpf.replace(/(\d{3})(\d)/,"$1.$2")
cpf=cpf.replace(/(\d{3})(\d)/,"$1.$2")
cpf=cpf.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{1,2})$/,"$1-$2")
return cpf
}

cpfCheck = function (el) {
    document.getElementById('cpfResponse').innerHTML = is_cpf(el.value)? '<span style="color:green">válido</span>' : '<span style="color:red">inválido</span>';
    if(el.value=='') document.getElementById('cpfResponse').innerHTML = '';
}
```

```html
<p>Digite o CPF:</p>
<p><input id="cpf" type="text" onkeyup="cpfCheck(this)" maxlength="18" onkeydown="javascript: fMasc( this, mCPF );"> <span id="cpfResponse"></span></p>
```

Comment: Olá eu acabei de testar seu código e acabei de colocar um cpf por exemplo 444.444.444-44 e esse está errado e não sei o que fazer

Comment: @GuilhermeHenrique, veja que na resposta destaquei `e acrescentando a validação de cpfs segundo a regra da receita federal`,  portanto, esse cpf `444.444.444-44`, segundo a receita federal,  não é um CPF válido. A quem interessa um CPF inválido? A minha resposta além da mascara só aceita CPFs realmente válidos, ao contrário das respostas

Comment: está mostrando valido pra 444.444.444-44

Answer (score 0):

Você pode deixar o cara digitar os números sem colocar os pontos e depois dar um replace com o código abaixo.

```
function replaceCPF(cpf){
  return cpf.replace(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2})/, "$1.$2.$3-$4");
}
```